# My condition is not working(prepared query and POST method + isset function)

Tags: php, mysql, isset

I'd like to verify if an user entered something in an input tag :

here is the index.php page :

```
<form action="email_validation.php" method="post">
    <p>
     Enter email :  <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" />
</p>
</form>
```

and the email_validation.php :

```
 if(isset($_POST['email']))
 {
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO newsletter(email) VALUES(:email)');
    $req->execute(array(
    'email' => $entree = $_POST['email']
));

echo 'Email added';
}
else
{
    echo 'Enter something';
}
```

It seems that my condition with isset() function is not working... when I'm testing this, "Email added" is displayed even if I'm not writing anything and a blank value is added to the database . When someone write nothing, I want to display "Enter something" and don't execute the query. I searched for hours and can't resolve this... Thanks is advance !

Comment: `'email' => $entree = $_POST['email']` what is $entree? Shouldn't this just be `'email' => $_POST['email']`

Comment: it's coming from an other 'test' but I removed it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not **validating** the input. You are just testing if the value exists. And it is, the _POST will have the email field, with an empty value. In order to validate it, the code should be:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $req....
} else {
    echo "No valid email provided";
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Everything is working well :))

Answer (score 0):

That's because `isset` will check if variable is set and is not `null`.

When you send your form without typing email `$_POST['email']` will contain empty string so `isset` will return `true`.

You have to use `empty` for that (or check length) and also it's good idea to additionally check if email is in correct format.